Mentalese and inner speech
Often, when I am thinking, it appears to me that I use words and sentences to formulate my thoughts. I use inner speech, silent speech, the stream of consciousness, so revered by Modernist writers. But do I really? It is as with being conscious. When you are asked if you are conscious now, you reflect and sure enough, you are conscious. But how about one minute ago? Well, you guess so. For more on this: Susan Blackmore.
It seems to me that with inner speech it could be just so. I found this out because I am bilingual. At times, after doing some thinking, I ask myself which language I was using. And sometimes I cannot tell. I found this baffling. The same goes when I suddenly stop my stream of consciousness and ask myself which words I was just using. Sometimes I am at a loss of words. Still, many people hold that inner speech is available to introspection.
All this is not to say that inner speech is always of an illusory nature and, of course, I can imagine a sentence word for word consciously, that is when I pay attention.
Another phenomenon is the word on the tip of your tongue. That means that you know conceptually that there is a word, only you have temporarily no access to that word. I don’t think I have ever experienced this problem with inner speech, but it happens regularly in conversation.
All this brings me to the Fodorian concept of mentalese.
I use the following definition here: Mentalese is a hypothetical language of thought, or the way that thoughts are represented in the mind without words.
1. Are these observations good arguments in favour of mentalese?
2. Are there other arguments?
3. Is it possible that human beings as a species could have had a sort of mentalese version of inner speech before language was acquired?
Or am I completely deluded and is introspection an unreliable methodology? I am open to this possibility.

Good thinking! Don't reinvent the wheel. There's lot of literature on the LOTH. ; ) And you're not deluded as far as I can tell.

Indeed - very nice observations. Imo introspection is not at all suitable or reliable as method to discover truths, but ... it is needed to make an initial phenomenological overview of findings - leading to further questions. The difficulty is to separate "innocent" phenomenology from prejudiced theory, in sofar as this is possible at all. (What may appear as "self-evident intuition" almost always contains a generalization - thus is clearly a theory. See Fischbein's classical study of Intuition in Science and Mathematics.)

This question is similar to: Is inner speech a quale?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JoWehler You seriously want me to edit my question to state that it is different from another question that is about qualia and doesn't mention mentalese and doesn't mention language of thought?  To be honest, the second answer relates, but if you want to close the question because I failed to read all questions on inner speech plus their answers to find an answer that relates, but not fully answers my questions, and you want this to be the bar, then you will be left with very few questions. So, no this answer on that question was not the answer I sought.

@JoWehler Close my question if you want.  I have already two answers that I am very happy with.

I suspect either the phenomena (or weighting of them) vary from one individual to the next.  I often think of things I can't explain easily, but am frequently called out by people who insist "you can't think of things without the words."  It would be interesting to see if there's any correlation between primarily linguistic thinkers and people who move their lips when they read.  :-)

Our internal thinking has many features, the assumption that it has only one (which has been assumed to be linguistic in modern analytic philosophy) is almost certainly false.
Thinking Fast and Slow details the experiments that reveal that most of our thinking is unconscious, and any "mentalese" we use unconsciously is -- not accessible to us. That our unconscious System 1 is a very fast processor, does associations very well, but does formal reasoning poorly, strongly suggests that system 1 operates as a purely neural net processor, and does not actually use "mentalese" at all.
System 2 of Thinking Fast uses language, and algorithmic thinking.  Whether this language is our external language is not fully clear, as your introspection questions about "what language was I thinking in" highlights.  If one accepts the "no single answer" point, you may well think in English, your other language, or a generic mentalese in different instances. An interesting aspect of Fast and Slow is that System 2 sometimes lies to itself about whether it did some thinking or not, when it is actually just rubber-stamping System 1 with rationalizations.  So sometimes when you thought you were thinking via system 2, it may just have been system 1 intuitionalism, and this could be why converting to external language then becomes a problem with words being stumbled over or "on the tip of the tongue".
We also have good reason to think that not all our conscious thinking is by "System 2".  One can be conscious of a sunset, or the glow of embers in a fire, but not able to readily articulate what one is thinking about or experiencing in either case.  I also do 3-D object manipulation transforms in my head non-linguistically.  These would be examples of non-linguistic, non-System 2, conscious thinking.
The model of consciousness developed by David Eagleman in Incognito, is that our unconsciousness packages a set of qualia and logic properties of our world and presents them to our consciousness in a shorthand summary form, like a theater stage, where just a few props imply a fully populated world of perception.  If our System 2 is being handed a limited content "story" with a pre-digested conclusion, then being unable to articulate linguistically the full reasoning behind what we think we think, or even the full CONTENT of what we think we think, is to be expected.
As language was a pretty late evolutionary event, the use of a non-linguistic "mentalese" in earlier primates, as well as in dogs, cats, sheep, etc. to do reasoning with is a reasonable expectation.  As it is useful to have a 2 stage control system, with a "System 2" cross-checking a "System 1" in all complex environments, it is also reasonable to expect that sub-rational animals likewise have system 2's checking on system 1, and the qualia passed to our minds by our system 1s may well be the sole method by which lower animals communicate between their systems 1 and 2.
These assumptions lead to the expectation that we think in all of the above:

Primary language
Secondary language
Mentalese
Geometrically
Qualia experiences
Unconsciously without realizing it

And yes, the last four would have preceded the evolutionary development of external language.

+1 Not only for mentioning Thinking Fast and Slow, but also for connecting the phenomena I mentioned with System I and II.

Yeah, ethology can add a lot to perspective in the question of mentalese because even our Great Ape relatives: gorillas, chimps, and bonobos all lack true language grammar. Thus, in a very real sense, one can point to chimps and show how much is capable with thought that doesn't involve language at all. You might be interested in the work of Michael Tomasello https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Tomasello

You are referring to what is known as the language of thought hypothesis (SEP) which was popular and is very much subject to scientific scrutiny. It's part of the broader inquiry into the relationship between language and thought. From the SEP article:

he language of thought hypothesis (LOTH) proposes that thinking occurs in a mental language. Often called Mentalese, the mental language resembles spoken language in several key respects: it contains words that can combine into sentences; the words and sentences are meaningful; and each sentence’s meaning depends in a systematic way upon the meanings of its component words and the way those words are combined.

None should doubt it is psychologically very appealing as a solution to characterizing thought since language is such an excellent window into thinking. For instance, Chomsy's transformational grammar represents syntactic constructions, but the use of constructions quickly led some to extend the theory to semantics and thought under the banner of generative semantics. This led to the linguistic wars. Thus, even linguists have had a difficulty in sussing out where language ends and thought begins.
These days there's criticism of the hypothesis that originates from modern cognitive science and connectionism which doesn't see thought as primarily linguistic, but rather primarily neural computational. In this view, language is how thought is serialized and externalized for communication, and not representative of how the brain functions to generate conscious and subconscious thought. This distinction between thought and language is often maintained in philosophy when we recognize that a linguistic utterance is not a logical proposition.
For more information, read the SEP and WP articles; here's a JSTOR paper "Languages of Thought" by Kaye that you might find worthwhile also. Note that in AI research this is also related to Newell and Simon's physical symbol hypothesis which posits that language-like computation is both necessary and sufficient for simulating human-level intelligence. This thinking is, following Haugeland, sometimes called GOFAI, and is criticized by implicitly and explicitly by connectionism and embodied cognition (SEP).
